# tcl string containing [digits]

Tags: tcl

I have a variable containing [some digits]
example:

```
set parse_var "Interface {} {} [1] [] 
FastEther0/1} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} 
unassigned {} {} {} {} {} YES unset {} administratively down down"
```

when I do puts `$parse_var` the script breaks because of `[1]`.

> invalid command name "1"
>       while executing
>   "1"

How do I handle this token, I need to split `parse_var` after puts statement

Comment: set parse_var "Interface {} {} [1]

Comment: Is there really an unbalanced brace after `FastEther0/1`? Yuck…

Answer (score 4):

That error doesn't occur on the `puts`, it occurs on the `set`. Double-quoted strings perform interpolation, so it's trying to run `[1]` immediately.

If the braces were balanced in your string, you could just replace the quotes with braces, but unfortunately you have an unbalanced close-brace after `FastEther0/1`. So instead, you may want to simply escape the `[`s with a `\`, like so:

```
set parse_var "Interface {} {} \[1] \[]
FastEther0/1} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
unassigned {} {} {} {} {} YES unset {} administratively down down"
```

Comment: for set parse_var "[1]" . Even though now the braces are balanced I get the same error  invalid command name "1" while executing "1"

Comment: I got it what you guys are saying. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2225716: { is a brace. [ is a bracket.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that you can't brace quote an unbalanced brace, unless it happens to have a preceding backslash or if you can put a backslash before it and the result will still be the same, like `eval {puts "\}"}`.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets have special meaning in Tcl: it invoke a command, in this case the command name is `1`, and return substitute the [...] with output of that command. It is called command substitution. To avoid that you can:

1. Use braces { ... } instead of quotes " ... "
2. Or, escaping, see Kevin Ballard's solution

If you want to use the braces:

```
set parse_var {Interface {} {} [1] [] 
FastEther0/1} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} 
unassigned {} {} {} {} {} YES unset {} administratively down down}
```

Comment: Did you try this? The braces in the string are mismatched. Notably. `FastEther0/1}` has no opening brace. This is why I suggested the escaping solution.

Comment: That's because user2225716 has a mis-matched brace that follows *FastEther0/1*. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Who says that's garbage? Maybe it's supposed to look like that.